# Installing CMS on ASP.NET website-Username and password for DB access

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I was just trying to install Umbraco CMS on my ASP.NET website. I am using the Web Platform installer from Umbraco http://umbraco.com/download

I pointed the CMS install to the local website folder where it was intended to be installed and specified to use an existing database for the same. It is asking for the username and password for the Database access. Is there some default value because I never configured the username and password for my DB? (It is a MS SQL Database)
Screenshot: http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/5920/webplatform.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is asking for SQL Server Authentication related details. This user id and password will be used by Umbraco to connect to SQL Server.

Kindly recall, you would have specified a password for user "sa" at the time of installation. If you don't remember then login to SQL Server with windows authentication and create a new user and specify the user id and password for that new user here.

HTH

Comment: SQL Server Express was installed with VS 2010 automatically. So, I don't think I specified a username and pass then. Could you please elaborate the steps on how to login? I do not have Management Studio Express installed and I would avoid that for now since I would have to install SQL Server SP2 as well.

Comment: Ok, I did install Management Studio Express too and created a new login. While I try to login in to the SQL management Studio, this error is given - > Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/nzq6i.jpg

Comment: For this you need to google it with Error code and description. There could be more than one reason this could be happening. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic496039-149-1.aspx#bm529888, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/e880c3be-a874-4979-8874-7044c087318d, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2004/07/23/192044.aspx,http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/66081a9e-686b-41eb-b99d-8967a6d2d03c. Since I have never worked with SQL express, I am providing some links which could help you.

Comment: Links provided are not to sort out your connection problem. Those are for default user id and password for SQL express.

Comment: I somehow got the SQL authentication working but Umbraco instal is giving some other now. "User or role does not exist in the database" Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Da7UL.jpg